# How can you tell which PageView was clicked on a DocumentViewer?

Tags: .net, wpf, documentviewer

It is pretty clear if only one page is visible but if multiple pages are visible, how can you tell which page the user clicks on?  I looked through its properties and nothing really stuck out.  Even if I find a way to show only one page at a time, it would be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an input hit test and turned that into a FixedPage.  If this was null, obviously a page was not clicked.  Then I went through every FixedPage in the DocumentViewer and found the matching page.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the IsMouseCaptured property.  I found this on the MSDN...

[UIElement.IsMouseCaptured on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ismousecaptured%28v=vs.85%29)